# How do I return a Promise on my Vuex store without getting an error message?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, state-management

I got the error below when I tried running my app,

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                    4:09:21 AM

This dependency was not found:

* core-js/fn/promise in ./src/store/index.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/fn/promise.
```

When I tried to install it, I bumped into another error message.

> Could not install from "core-js/fn/promise" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: Please show the store

Answer (score 0):

i know this post is old but, I had the same problem.
You can fix that with this command

```
npm install es6-promise --save
```

in the vueX documentation :
https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#promise